# Фоновая полупрозрачная картинка

Tags: html, css

Приветствую всех вошедших.

Есть `background rgba` - можно сделать полупрозрачный цвет фона, есть `opacity` - можно сделать полупрозрачный фон (в т.ч. картинку), но минус в том, что все, что в нутри этого стиля тоже становиться полупрозрачным.

Подскажите, как сделать фоновую картинку полупрозрачную, не изменив прозрачность вложенных элементов? Можно ли это сделать только на css?

```
<div class="полупрозрачный фон">
<div class="какой то див">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хм, а нельзя сделать как-то так:

    <div> <!-- container -->
        <div class="полупрозрачный фон"/>
        <div class="какой то див">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>

(надо разместить их так, чтобы накладывались)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно сделать так, чтобы один был блок абсолютно позиционирован,а другой, с контентом, накрывал его, причем обоим блокам нужно задавать одинаковые параметры, типа `width`/`height`.

Например: http://jsfiddle.net/62cF5/

Советую либо использовать если это фон: `rgba`, прозрачную `png`, если это картинка: способ, что выше, либо прозрачную `png`, причем способ, что выше - для фона без повторений.

Comment: Жаль, что по другому никак. Но способ с z-index тоже нормальный

Answer (score 3):

Сделайте из картинки PNG с полупрозрачностью и всё.

Comment: Если это картинка 1000х1000, лучше будет сохранить её в jpg. и добавить прозрачность способами браузера.

Comment: Чем лучше? Тем, что png не теряет информацию?

Comment: @lampa, естественно универсального ответа нет. Стоит исходить из конкретной задачи.

Comment: @alexlz тем, что png-24 будет весить в 2-3 раза больше, чем jpg с качеством 70%

Comment: была бы одна картинка - согласен абсолютно, можно было бы ее под редактировать. Но картинок много. Да и размер у них большой, даже в jpg формате